Single millinewton strain gauge suggestions
I am working on a project where the precise & accurate measurement of single millinewton forces has become a significant boundary. Is there a cost effective device that is able to measure such small forces?

Consider to check out the help section, specifically https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic in which it notes that requests to find or recommend products is discouraged. In this case, "cost effective" also becomes a subjective type of question, heading toward opinions, also discouraged. If you can edit your question to focus on a specific engineering reference, you may be more successful.

Look at Cavendish's experiments with torsion wires used to measure gravity.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

1 millinewton is equivalent to the weight of a toothpick (100 mg). There are plenty of milligram scales available online for $20 or less. Microgram scales start at about 10x that.
